# join 2 variables, each one pointing to something different

Tags: bash, shell, variables

I want to do a 'for' loop where two variables would be joined. Here is the situation

Initial set of variables, each one pointing to a file :

```
weather_sunny=/home/me/foo
weather_rainy/home/me/bar
weather_cloudy=/home/me/sth
```

2nd set of variables :

```
sunny
rainy
cloudy
```

Now, I want to do something like this...

```
for today in sunny rainy cloudy ; do
    cat ${weather_$today}
done
```

But I don't succeed getting the content of the initial variables. How can I achieve this ?

Answer (score 4):

You can get the names of the variables easily enough:

```
for today in ${!weather_*}; do
    echo cat "${!today}"
done
cat /home/me/foo
cat /home/me/bar
cat /home/me/sth
```

But if you're using bash 4+, you can use an associative array for this. In bash 4,

```
$ declare -A weather
$ weather['sunny']=/home/me/sth
$ weather['humid']=/home/me/oth
$ for today in "${!weather[@]}"; do echo "${weather[$today]}"; done
/home/me/sth
/home/me/oth
```

Comment: You can also avoid hardcoding the list of array keys: `for today in "${!weather[@]}"; do`

Comment: @chepner Thanks, I was all wrapped up in avoiding eval and didn't even notice the hard-coding. Fixed.

Answer (score 2):

```
for today in sunny rainy cloudy ; do
  eval e="\$weather_$today"
  cat $e
done
```

Comment: Avoid `eval` when there is another option available.

Answer (score 1):

Inroduce temporary variable and then use indirect expansion(introduced by `!` character).

```
for today in sunny rainy cloudy ; do
  tmp="weather_$today"
  cat ${!tmp}
done
```

I don't know how to stay within one line though.